# how to use e.target.name in redux toolKit?

Tags: reactjs, redux-toolkit

I am a Korean junior developer.
I am changing the react to redux-toolKit.
But I don't know how to manage e.target.name with the redux-toolKit.
Could you give me some help?

My code(react)

```
const [passengerInfo, setPassengerInfo] = useState({
  adult: 1,
  child: 0,
  baby: 0,
  rating: '전체',
});
const { adult, child, baby, rating } = passengerInfo;

const plusPassengerNumber = e => {
  const { name } = e.target;
  setPassengerInfo(prev => ({ ...prev, [name]: prev[name] + 1 }));
};

const minusPassengerNumber = e => {
  const { name } = e.target;
  setPassengerInfo(prev => ({ ...prev, [name]: prev[name] - 1 }));
};
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8CLms.png)

Comment: React and Redux are two different things.

Comment: The snippet which you shared has nothing to do with redux-toolkit, this handlers are for local state management, nothing to convert for redux-toolkit